Why the from property not working in SPFx?
I want to send an email with a custom sender, but some reason it always says SharePoint Online.
    await pnp.sp.utility.sendEmail({
        From: "Tester",
        To: ["test@example.hu"],
        Subject: "Test",
        Body: "Hi this is a test email",
    })


That's not a valid email address. It needs to be "Tester@somedomain"
